# How can I get a reference to current project in a sbt subproject build.sbt file

Tags: plugins, playframework, sbt

I have a playframework subproject. Currently I'm defining it as a playframework module in the parent `build.sbt`

```
lazy val silhouetteModule = (project in file("modules/silhouette"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

I would prefer to delegate that knowledge to the child project `build.sbt`. How can I call in the child project this enablePlugins?

```
import play.PlayScala

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

name := "play-silhouette-seed"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "1.0",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.0",
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.0-beta4",
  cache
)

//this doesn't work
currentThisProject.enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `enablePlugins` directly in your `build.sbt` file for the subproject:

```scala
enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```